# Is it possible to send an input once a second through Lua scripting in BizHawk?

Tags: lua, emulation

I am fairly new to Lua scripting in BizHawk and was wondering if it was possible to set it up such that it sends a varying input every second to the emulator. I am aware that OBS has a function called `script_tick(seconds)` which is called every frame. Does BizHawk allow for similar functionality where I can do the same? I had a scan through the documentation and found nothing of the sort, although it is possible that I completely missed it.

Many thanks for your time in advance!